# python scraping from php form

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the table from https://www.allflicks.net/, it turns out that you need to load the javascript(?) for the content before the table is populated. I have researched into selenium and doing it that way but my aim is to use the python script on headless servers and i was trying to avoid more install requirements e.g firefox or chrome. So i dug deeper to find that the information comes via json which is perfect.
a POST request is sent to: `https://www.allflicks.net/wp-content/themes/responsive/processing/processing_us.php` with a LOT of data. According to chrome inspect, "form data".

So i created this in python

```
payload = {"draw": "1", "columns[0][data]": "box_art", "columns[0][name]": "", "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[0][orderable]": "false", "columns[0][search][value]": "", "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[1][data]": "title", "columns[1][name]": "", "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[1][orderable]": "true", "columns[1][search][value]": "", "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[2][data]": "year", "columns[2][name]": "", "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[2][orderable]": "true", "columns[2][search][value]": "", "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[3][data]": "genre", "columns[3][name]": "", "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[3][orderable]": "true", "columns[3][search][value]": "", "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[4][data]": "rating", "columns[4][name]": "", "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[4][orderable]": "true", "columns[4][search][value]": "", "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[5][data]": "available", "columns[5][name]": "", "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[5][orderable]": "true", "columns[5][search][value]": "", "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[6][data]": "director", "columns[6][name]": "", "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[6][orderable]": "true", "columns[6][search][value]": "", "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
           "columns[7][data]": "cast", "columns[7][name]": "", "columns[7][searchable]": "true",
           "columns[7][orderable]": "true", "columns[7][search][value]": "", "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
           "order[0][column]": "5", "order[0][dir]": "desc", "start": "0", "length": "100", "search[value]": "",
           "search[regex]": "false", "movies": "false", "shows": "true", "documentaries": "false", "min": "1900",
           "max": "2017"}

url = "https://www.allflicks.net/wp-content/themes/responsive/processing/processing_us.php"

headers = {'Host': 'www.allflicks.net',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'Content-Length': '1879',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Origin': 'https://www.allflicks.net',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Referer': 'https://www.allflicks.net/'
           }

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

print r.json()
```

But this only returns the 200 response code with no data. I copied the headers and data from chrome inspect. Is it possible there is a block to sending post requests unless from the server?

Comment: Did you try to replay this request with curl first? I have seen servers that won't send data to an IP that hasn't sent a get to the homepage first, but there might be something wrong with the request itself. Before checking if there is some weird IP session handling you should be sure the request works.

Comment: Probably a cookies issue. Create a session with requests instead (session = requests.Session()) and then call first the baseurl to get the cookie (response = session.get(url)). After that do the request you did but again use session.post (as session has your cookie from the first call).

Comment: Cheers for that responses. I tried sessions and curl, both return no data at all. Could there be some weird protection with the php file to stop the data being scraped?